# Is there a way to not take trade at opening of market?

Tags: pine-script

If there is any open position it gets closed due to fluctuations when market opens i.e. at 9.15.
Is there any way to like not take any trade for first 5 minutes?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a session time and set your desired start and end times.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

timeAllowed = input.session("0920-1500", "Allowed hours")
timeIsAllowed = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed + ":1234567")
c = timeIsAllowed ? color.new(color.blue, 85) : na
bgcolor(c)
```

[image]